# Как называется круглый счётчик с цифрами и прогрессом по окружности?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-library

Здравствуйте, как называется подобный счетчик? С каждым выполненным действием - он увеличивается на 1 единицу и круг постепенно заполняется. Есть ли уроки или готовые примеры по этому счётчику? (это не progress bar)[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартного контрола такого нет, но есть сторонние решения. Судя по [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27266585/3212712), вам вот эта библиотека подойдёт: [CircleProgress](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress)

```
<com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.CircleProgress
    android:id="@+id/circle_progress"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    custom:circle_progress="20"/>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Вот пример такого `progressBar`, но без цифр внутри, с ними можно сделать скомпоновав `ProgressBar` и `TextView` внутри RelativeLayout, к примеру!

```
progressBarCircular = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
progressBarCircular.setMax(100);
```

в разметке его вставить так:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/result_check_progress_bar_height"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/result_check_progress_bar_height"
    android:rotation="-90"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="0"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/shape_circular"
    />
```

**shape_circular.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  >
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
            <shape
                android:shape="ring"
                android:useLevel="true"
                android:thickness="5sp">
            </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress"  >

         <shape
                android:innerRadius="55dp"
                android:shape="ring"
                android:useLevel="true"
                android:thickness="6.0sp">

                <rotate
                    android:fromDegrees="0"
                    android:toDegrees="360"
                    />
                <solid android:color="#70ed70"/>
            </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```